# Kubernetes terminates pod due to OOM while below limit

Tags: kubernetes, out-of-memory

I'am playing with memory leaks in Go on K8s cluster. I've got the "leaker" application setup with memory limit 256MB. My test scenario is to cause OOM in the app. From metrics I see that K8s terminates "leaker" pod after it reached the memory limit - that's clear.

Now is the part that I don't understand: after first termination, k8s spawns new pod but this one and every next pod is terminated way below the limit (limit is still 256MB).

It look like this:

- 1st pod terminates after reaching limit(256MB)
- 2nd, 3rd and 4th pod terminates after reaching 150MB
- 5th, 6th pod terminates after reaching 200MB

It looks like some throttling mechanism. I can't find anything about it in documentation or web.

Comment: What you describe is a very common problem that occurs when some applications don't release memory correctly.

Very common with Java applications in general... Try running a GC first.

Comment: Please consider creating a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so others can try to see what you are seeing.

Comment: @glv I've made that memory leak on purpose.

Comment: Is there available resources on the node?

Comment: @Jonas yes, there are plenty of memory and cpu available.

Comment: **spec.containers[].resources.limits** is passed to the container runtime when the kubelet starts a container. CPU is considered a "compressible" resource. If your app starts hitting your CPU limits, Kubernetes starts throttling your container, giving your app potentially worse performance. Refer to official [doc](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2021/11/26/qos-memory-resources/#how-does-it-work) for more details.

Comment: Can you try without limits? I have seen cases where when the memory allocation happens too fast, and even before the metric server scraps, the pods gets killed.

Comment: @titogeo you're right, firstly I did perf test with only 1 req/s so it was smooth, then with 50 req/s. I checked it twice and that's metrics scrapper fault, it was too slow and allocation was to fast. Thank you for that.

Comment: @VeeraNagireddy Thank you for this docs reference. I did not know about the throttle factor etc.